# programmatically ActionSheet's Buttons

Tags: iphone, ios4

I need some guidance for following :

- I have an ActionSheet. When it appears it shows my custom view with two buttons.
- The View is called from another (.h/.m)file using xib.
- How can I set cancel event on one of the button. Buttons are added into view not in ActionSheet.
- OR How can I put buttons on ActionSheet programmatically ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [link](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/) to your answer.

Also you can refere the [Class Reference for UIActionsheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get all the solutions related to action sheet.

Comment: but my buttons are placed on the view and view is placed on ActionSheet.

Comment: You need to insert uiaction sheet in the uiview , you might done the opposite.

Comment: Fun : its not like that ... i have added uiaction sheet in view but my uiaction sheet display the another view as well..

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own action sheet. For this you have to make a view controller and you can use it as action sheet by using

[self presentModalViewController:YourViewController animated:YES];

And on cancel btn action you can do

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove that view from superview when user tap on cancel button.